# unknown property 'supportLibVersion' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am getting following error

> Could not get unknown property 'supportLibVersion' for object of type 
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHand

I am working on react-native application and react-native-maps dependencies are below in which I am getting error

```
 dependencies {
      def supportLibMajorVersion = supportLibVersion.split('\\.')[0] as int
      def appCompatLibName =  (supportLibMajorVersion < 20) ? "androidx.appcompat:appcompat" : "com.android.support:appcompat-v7"
      implementation "$appCompatLibName:$supportLibVersion"
      implementation('com.facebook.react:react-native:+') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
      }
      implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:${safeExtGet('playServicesVersion', '16.1.0')}"
      implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${safeExtGet('playServicesVersion', '16.1.0')}"
      implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    }
```

Anyone have idea what is wrong here?

The error in terminal is

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> Where:
>   Build file 'D:\react native\abhishek\Gwala\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\build.gradle' line: 20
>
> What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-maps'.
>   Could not get unknown property 'supportLibVersion' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

line 20 is

```
def supportLibMajorVersion = supportLibVersion.split('\\.')[0] as int
```

Answer (score 46):

Add `supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"` inside `android/build.gradle` -> `ext`

example:

```
ext {
  buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
  minSdkVersion = 16
  compileSdkVersion = 28
  targetSdkVersion = 28
  supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Hi @Dhaval, thanks for your answer. Would you mind editing your post with an explanation that can teach others how your answer solves the problem in question?

Comment: worked for me. just add supportLibVersion = "28.0.0" to ext section in build.gradle file.

Comment: Thanks. To make things clearer, the build.gradle file that is to be edited is the one in android, not in android/app. android/build.gradle has buildscript { ext {} } on top.

Comment: @Mahdi Thanks after struggle two days finally get an answer, is this will work fine in ios also

Comment: @Mahdi if i am creating new project and add react-native-maps then it's working fine if i am using my old project then i am getting error. i don't know why

Answer (score 13):

Add `supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"` to `buildscript` in `android/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"  // <=== add this line
    }

    ...
}
```

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/3108#issuecomment-552795543

Comment: Now that we are forced to change compileSdkVersion to 29, what should we do with the rest of the properties? Keep them as they were? (28.0.0) Increase them? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Try installing it directly from github:

`npm install --save git+https://git@github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps.git`

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue after these steps:

1. Add this line to `\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\build.gradle -- line: 20`

   `def supportLibVersion = safeExtGet('supportLibVersion', '28.0.0')`
2. In the `AndroidManifest.xml` under `<application>`:

   `<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>`

Answer (score 2):

Add below line in `node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android/build.gradle`:

under `dependencies`

```
def supportLibVersion = safeExtGet('supportLibVersion', '28.0.0')
```

Example:
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/lib/android/build.gradle

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your file build.gradle inside the android directory

> (.../YourApp/android/build.gradle)

find the ext section and add

> supportLibVersion = "28.0.0" ext {
>       ...
>       supportLibVersion = "28.0.0" }

that should do the work.